# toFixed Isn't Doing Anything

Tags: javascript

I'm teaching myself JavaScript and have run into a problem with toFixed().  I'm working through an amortization calculator; and, one of the steps returns a number with a huge number of decimal places. I'm trying to cut it down to 4 decimal places. 
Be advised the sample code has a lot of explanatory HTML in it. It's only there so that I can work through the steps of the equation.  Also, when I add one to the very long number, it adds the numeral one to end of the scientific notation.

```
var paymentamount;
var principal=250000;
var interestrate = 4.5;
var annualrate = interestrate/12;
var numberofpayments = 360;
document.write("This is the annuitized interest rate: "+ annualrate +"%");
document.write("<h3> Now we add 1 to the annualized interest rate</h3>");
var RplusOne = annualrate + 1;
document.write("<p> This is One Added to R: " + RplusOne + "%");
document.write("<h3>Next RplusOne is Raised to the power of N </h3>");
var RRaised = (Math.pow(RplusOne, numberofpayments)).toFixed(4);
document.write("<p>This gives us the following very long number, even thought it shouldn't: " + RRaised);
document.write("<h3>Now we add one to the very long number </h3>");
var RplusOne = RRaised + 1;
document.write("<p>Now we've added one: " + RplusOne);
```

Comment: The `.toFixed()` function returns a **string**, not a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

> If number is greater than 1e+21, this method simply calls Number.prototype.toString() and returns a string in exponential notation.

The problem is that you are using `4.5` as your interest rate instead of `0.045`, so doing this:

```
Math.pow(4.5 / 12 + 1, 360)
```

gives you a huge number (`6.151362770461608e+49` or `6.15 * 10^49` to be exact). Change your interest rate to `0.045` and you will get what you are expecting.

As for the `var RplusOne = RRaised + 1` line, the problem here is that `RRaised` is a string because of `toFixed`. I would only call `toFixed` when you're displaying things, and not at any other time; the primary reason for this would be to avoid rounding errors in subsequent calculations, but has the added benefit that your variables remain numbers and not strings.

Comment: Thanks.  That was a stupid math error on my part.  A rate of 450% is pretty high.

Comment: `RRaised` will still be a string due to `toFixed`'s return type, so `+ 1` will still append the character `1` to it instead of performing arithmetic.

Comment: You can change the next-to-last line to `var RplusOne = RRaised*1 + 1;`.  That will type-cast RRaised as a number.

Comment: @RickHitchcock `parseFloat` would probably be a better and clearer way to cast in this case.

Comment: I would say to only call `toFixed` when you are displaying the number, not before then.

Comment: Agreed, do your math before calling `toFixed` so that you don't have to deal with casting from a string back to a number from the `toFixed` call.

Comment: @robbrit, agreed.  That would save trouble if RRaised is used in the future.